# Laravel Trying to get property of non-object but not sure why

Tags: laravel-4

I want to grab some data from a database and display on a layout page, I've basically started building a small CMS to get into Laravel and all has gone fine so far but now i'm at a wall, and can't find a solution.

I have a layout blade file like so: http://paste.laravel.com/1fB1 nothing majot but you will see i have used $page->meta_title etc in there and in my controller i have:

```
    public function home()
{
    $pages = Pages::all();
    return View::make('frontend/home')->with('pages',$pages);
}
```

Which I have a pages model doing nothing else really like so:

```
   class Pages extends Eloquent {

  protected $table = 'pages';
    }
```

So why is it trying to get property of non-object and I don't really want to use a foreach because this is going to be the frontend of my 'test' website so a foreach wouldn't suite.

Comment: Please include the complete error messafe.

Comment: Pages::find(1) works but I want all pages to loaded so to speak if i add more pages via the cms i want it to show the page created

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$meta_title

Comment: Have you tried accessing the variable as `$pages[0]['field_name_here']`?

Comment: @James Binford  Yes that seems to have worked, why is that because its been cast to json?

Comment: These `::all()` queries seem to pass the result as a multi-dimensional array.  I've added my response as an Answer.  Accept it if you like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to access these items as a multi-dimensional array if you don't want to loop through them.

`$pages[0]['field_name_here']`

or

`$pages[1]['field_name_here']`

Comment: Or could i just use @section() for each of these?

Comment: In Blade, `@section` is used to separate sections in your template file.  I use this for my menus.  That wouldn't fit your need here.

Comment: althought this {{ $pages[0]['page_content'] }} is working it's not showing the correct content for each different page....now i'm stuck!!!!! :(

Comment: Your query pulls all content related to your model.  If you're trying to show distinct content for each page, you'll need to be more specific with the data you're pulling from the database :)

Comment: Are you trying to get page data based on the ID of the record?

Comment: No i'm a laravel newb and ive built a CMS which all works fine, and now i'm working on the frontend so I need it pull the correct data for which ever slug is clicked

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43554/discussion-between-james-binford-and-the-unforgiven-ii)

Comment: Joined chat, were we can continue if you are willing to help advise

Comment: This return the whatever is entered in the URL but how can i get it to work with the controller?

    Route::get('/{slug}', function($slug)
     {
        return 'Page is '.$slug;
     });

Comment: Open that as a question and I'll answer it.  These comments are getting too long and off topic from the original  :)

Comment: join the chat if you want

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit of a tough one to answer without knowing how you want your CMS to work.

For example, you could have a route as `{pagename}` in your routes.php file, then have a page controller where you would get the requested route from the variable passed in. This would then load the page you wanted using the variable

```
public function page( $pagename ) {
    $page = Page::where('page_title', '=', $pagename)->first();

    View::make('frontend/page', array( 'page' => $page ));
}
```

Using a route like that, and the controller, in your view you could use `{{ $page->content }}` to get the content of the requested page from the database and display it.

Hope this helps.

Edit: Example Route:

```
Route::get('{pagename}', 'PageController@page');
```